# shell script to only keep the latest two tar files, but delete all other tar files?

Tags: shell, backup, tar, system-administration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete all but the most recent X files in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785/delete-all-but-the-most-recent-x-files-in-bash)

The scenerio is as follows:

Two tar files will be created in one directory per day, but I need only the latest two files, so how to delete the other files automatically each day?

Is i possible to write this script using pure shell commands, and not with high level language such as perl, python or ruby...

This issue is a bit similar to [FTP - Only want to keep latest 10 files - delete LRU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088848/ftp-only-want-to-keep-latest-10-files-delete-lru) and [how to delete all files except the latest three in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447326/how-to-delete-all-files-except-the-latest-three-in-a-folder)

**but mine also needs to test if a tar file is corrupt**

If newer tar file is corrupt, I would not keep it, but reserve the older ones, so what the script should be like?

Comment: How (command and options) do you test tar files for integrity?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is solvable using a two pass approach.

1. Detect and remove corrupt tar files.
2. Remove all but the latest N files as described in the referenced question.

The first pass could be performed with something along

```
for t in *.tar; do
    if program_that_checks_tar_file_for_integrity $t; then
        : # OK
    else
        rm $t
    fi
done
```